# Tinymce disappears after ajax form submit in MVC partialview

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, tinymce

I have a form on an ASP.NET MVC 4 partial view and also another partial view of list is on this partial view. I have a Tinymce to save some notes.

When I save the form using

```
Ajax.BeginForm(.... with AjaxOptions InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
```

to update the list below. Now when the form submits then everything is fine and new record is also showing in the list but the Tinymce editor disappears.

If anybody have any idea please help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your replacing the element that `tinymce` was applied to?

Comment: my code to initialize the tinymce is in a seperate script file that is always on the main page as it is on Layout page

Comment: Yes but you need to attach `tinymce` to an element (`textarea`). Is that `textarea` replaced by a new `textarea` when you submit the form?

Comment: actually the ajax  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace does the page to reset the partial view HTML DOM, hence my tinymce is no more editor in this case I want when the ajax refresh my partial view the textarea I have to become tinymce editor again.

Comment: As I suspected, so you need to reattach `tinymce` to the new element

Comment: I did try to initialize tinymce on "OnComplete" event of ajax option but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The Tinymce does not like you reinitializing it. So you have to remove it before loading it again.
Use: tinyMCE.remove() oncomplete or other exit and it will be there next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyPage", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "detail", OnBegin = "tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'id-of-your-textarea-here');" }))
```

Then on page load, you need:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'Text');
```